# Invalid bind-variable name in Zend framework with Mysqli

Tags: zend-framework, mysqli

I was working on a application with Zend Framework and PDO_MYSQL Adapter.

But my client server doesnt support PDO_MYSQL

I changed the adapter to Mysqli and I'm getting this error:

> Invalid bind-variable name

How to resolve it?

Comment: Beware of [issue 30](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/issues/30) in Zend Framework 1.12 as it can trigger this exception if your SQL contains a quoted value with both a colon and any escaped control characters such as newlines.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately MySQLi doesn't actually support named parameters, but the Exception message isn't really clear on that, despite being thrown in this block of code:

```
if ($this->_adapter->supportsParameters('named') === false) {
    /**
     * @see Zend_Db_Statement_Exception
     */
    require_once 'Zend/Db/Statement/Exception.php';
    throw new Zend_Db_Statement_Exception("Invalid bind-variable name '$val'");
}
```

The Exception should really say:

> You are trying to use named parameters
>   with an adapter that doesn't support
>   them

The solution is easy, just switch your adapter from Mysqli to Pdo_Mysql.

[Reference](http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/zend-framework/zend-framework-error-invalid-bind-variable-name-solution/).

Comment: Oh! but the customer needs to agree to change the server he has...
Is there any solution to work with out named parameters?

Comment: Either change your code not to use named parameters, or simply configure your application to use pdo_mysql extension instead of mysqli.

Comment: To clarify: switching from `MySQLi` to `Pdo_Mysql` would only require a change on the PHP side if PHP doesn't have it compiled in or loaded as a module. It doesn't require a change on the MySQL server side.